# using SHLIB to compile and load standalone Rcpp function

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to compile the following function with `SHLIB` (saved as `foo.cpp`):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

RcppExport SEXP foo( SEXP x, SEXP y){
        Rcpp::NumericVector xx(x), yy(y) ;
        int n = xx.size() ;
        Rcpp::NumericVector res( n ) ;
        double x_ = 0.0, y_ = 0.0 ;
        for( int i=0; i<n; i++){
                x_ = xx[i] ;
                y_ = yy[i] ;
                if( x_ < y_ ){
                        res[i] = x_ * x_ ;
                } else {
                        res[i] = -( y_ * y_) ;
                }
        }
        return res ;
}
```

I try

```
$ R CMD SHLIB foo.cpp 
/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.4 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64  -I/opt/local/include    -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c foo.cpp -o foo.o
foo.cpp:1:18: error: Rcpp.h: No such file or directory
foo.cpp:3: error: 'RcppExport' does not name a type
make: *** [foo.o] Error 1
```

How do I include this file, and is this the right way to compile a standalone function with Rcpp? Of course, I have installed Rcpp with `install.packages('Rcpp')`.

**Update:**
Trying to find the location of Rcpp.h in R I get:

```
> system.file("lib", "Rcpp.h", package="Rcpp")
[1] ""
>
```

However,

```
> Rcpp:::LdFlags()
/opt/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/lib/x86_64/libRcpp.a>
```

**Update 2:**

Looking at http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg79185.html, I tried

```
$ PKG_CPPFLAGS=`Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::CxxFlags()'` \
>          PKG_LIBS=`Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::LdFlags()'` \
>          R CMD SHLIB foo.cpp
/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.4 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -I/opt/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include -I/opt/local/include    -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c foo.cpp -o foo.o
/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.4 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/opt/local/lib -o foo.so foo.o /opt/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/lib/x86_64/libRcpp.a -L/opt/local/lib/R/lib/x86_64 -lR
```

and it generated `foo.o` and `foo.so`. How do I import this in R now?

**Update 3:**
So it can be loaded from `dyn.load` as

```
> dyn.load("foo.so")
> is.loaded("foo")
[1] TRUE
```

It can be called successfully as as

```
> .Call("foo",x=as.numeric(c(1,2,3)),y=as.numeric(c(4,5,6)))
[1] 1 4 9
```

Although the function is not visible as such.

```
> foo
Error: object 'foo' not found
```

Comment: Keep searching and reading the documentation.  For your most recent question, read the See Also section of `?SHLIB`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich, thanks for the downvote, but from the See Also section, do you mean `library.dynam`? `library.dynam("foo")`, `library.dynam("foo.o")`, and `library.dynam("foo.so")` still give me errors.

Comment: You're clearly not reading the documentation.  `?library.dynam` says it should really only be used inside a package, specifically `.onLoad`.  Please read and understand the documentation before trying stuff and reporting "errors".

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich, thanks! I finally got it.

Comment: The Rcpp package has eight vignettes, and in particular one that is aptly named 'Rcpp-FAQ' which covers this in question 2.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is clearly addressed in Question 2.4. of the [Rcpp-FAQ](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf).

Comment: This is now item 2.5 – oddly, on my machine (OS X), `Rcpp:::LdFlags()` is empty. Is that a bug? Compilation seems to work fine.

Comment: It's a feature, see the Rcpp 0.11.0 release notes, or maybe a dozen questions here and on rcpp-devel. Compiling via `R CMD SHLIB` is still   a bad idea though.

Answer (score 2):

The answer I found is that `SHLIB` needs to be provided the location of the Rcpp files. This can be done as

```
$ PKG_CPPFLAGS=`Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::CxxFlags()'` \
>          PKG_LIBS=`Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::LdFlags()'` \
>          R CMD SHLIB foo.cpp
```

Then, the compiled file can be loaded in R as

```
> dyn.load("foo.so")
```

and it can be called in R as

```
> .Call("foo",c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6))
```

Comment: None of which is any different than non-Rcpp packages would be built and loaded, and clearly documented in "Writing R Extensions".  All that is different here is your need for `-I` and `-L` flags for Rcpp -- which is why we recommend using the `inline` package.